Getting unwanted not secure web window on trying to perform any action on any web element on current webpage
Screenshot of my code output
I tried the below code to navigate to a browser enter url - https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/demo and perform click action on a web element. But on trying to perform this on any web element via my below mentioned step definition file, I am getting unwanted not secure web window along with my browser window where the URL got entered successfully. Please note that this is happening for any website I am trying to automate. Any help is appreciated. JAi Shree Ram and Dhanyawaad in advance.
package StepDefinitions;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;

import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;

public class OpencartDemoNavigation {
    
    private WebDriver driver;
    
    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
    // Setting up things for successful navigation to unsecured websites
    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    

    // Declaring webdriver element
    driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
    }
    

    @Given("chrome browser is open")
    public void chrome_browser_is_open() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();

        System.out.println("Inside Step - Chrome browser is open");

        // Get current project path
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        // Display project path
        System.out.println("The current project path is: " + projectPath);

        // Set system property for chrome driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", projectPath + "/src/test/resources/Drivers/msedgedriver.exe");

        // Maximize browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    @When("user enters opencart demo URL in the chrome address bar and hits enter")
    public void user_enters_opencart_demo_url_in_the_chrome_address_bar_and_hits_enter() throws InterruptedException {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();

        System.out.println("Inside Step - User enters opencart demo URL in the chrome address bar and hits enter");

        driver.get("https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/demo");
        
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        
        //driver.navigate().to("https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/demo");
        
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[text()='Features']/ancestor::nav/..//div[contains(@class,'container')]/..//a[text()='Features']")).click();

    }

//  @Then("user gets navigated to opencart demo landing page")
//  public void user_gets_navigated_to_opencart_demo_landing_page() {
//      // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
//      // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
//      System.out.println("Inside Step - User gets redirected to opencart demo store landing page");
//
//      // Get the web page title and display it
//      String currentPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
//      System.out.println("The current page title is: " + currentPageTitle);
//
//  }
//
    @When("user clicks opencart demo storefront tab")
    public void user_clicks_opencart_demo_storefront_tab() throws InterruptedException {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();

        System.out.println("Inside Step - User clicks opencart demo storefront tab");

        // Click the web element after hover
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Features']/ancestor::nav/..//div[contains(@class,'container')]/..//a[text()='Features']")).click();

    }

//  @Then("user gets redirected to opencart demo store landing page")
//  public void user_gets_redirected_to_opencart_demo_store_landing_page() {
//      // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
//      // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
//      
//      System.out.println("Inside Step - User gets redirected to opencart demo store landing page");
//      
//      // Get the web page title and display it
//      String currentPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
//      System.out.println("The current page title is: "+currentPageTitle);
//                      
//      // Set the expected page title
//      // String expectedPageTitle = "";
//                      
//      // Verify the page title
//      // Assert.assertEquals("Page title didn't match", expectedPageTitle, currentPageTitle); 
//      
//  }

}


I am getting the following error inspite of the fact that, element locator is correct. I tried
getWindowHAndles, driver.switchTo(), driver.navigate.To(), but no use.
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='Features']/ancestor::nav/..//div[contains(@class,'container')]/..//a[text()='Features']"}

I found out the root cause of the issue and it was due to the message that was being popped up that chrome is being controlled by automated software. The below code helped to resolve my issue.
package StepDefinitions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

import io.cucumber.java.en.*;

public class OpencartDemoNavigation {

    WebDriver driver;

//  @Before
//  public void browserSetup() {
//
//      // Get current project path
//      String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
//
//      // Display project path
//      System.out.println("The current project path is: " + projectPath);
//
//      // Set system property for chrome driver
//      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath + 
"/src/test/resources/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
//      
//      // Declaring chrome options
//      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//      options.setBinary("E:\\Automation 
Testing\\Chrome_And_ChromeDriver\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe");
//
//      // Declaring webdriver element
//      driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        // driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // driver.get("https://www.google.com");

//  }

@Given("chrome browser is open")
public void chrome_browser_is_open() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();

    System.out.println("Inside Step - Chrome browser is open");

    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

    // Declaring chrome options
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    List<String> eSwitches = new ArrayList<>();

    eSwitches.add("enable-automation");

    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", eSwitches);
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    // Maximize browser window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}

@When("user enters opencart demo URL in the chrome address bar and hits enter")
public void user_enters_opencart_demo_url_in_the_chrome_address_bar_and_hits_enter() throws InterruptedException {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();

    System.out.println("Inside Step - User enters opencart demo URL in the chrome address bar and hits enter");

    driver.get("https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/demo");

    Thread.sleep(8000);

    // driver.navigate().to("https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/demo");

    // driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[text()='Features']/ancestor::nav/..//div[contains(@class,'container')]/..//a[text()='Features']")).click();

}

//  @Then("user gets navigated to opencart demo landing page")
//  public void user_gets_navigated_to_opencart_demo_landing_page() {
//      // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
//      // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
//      System.out.println("Inside Step - User gets redirected to opencart demo store landing page");
//
//      // Get the web page title and display it
//      String currentPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
//      System.out.println("The current page title is: " + currentPageTitle);
//
//  }
//
@When("user clicks opencart demo storefront tab")
public void user_clicks_opencart_demo_storefront_tab() throws InterruptedException {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();

    System.out.println("Inside Step - User clicks opencart demo storefront tab");

    // Click the web element after hover
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "//a[@class='box-overlay']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'container')]/..//span[normalize-space()='View Store Front']"))
            .click();

}

//  @Then("user gets redirected to opencart demo store landing page")
//  public void user_gets_redirected_to_opencart_demo_store_landing_page() 
{
//      // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
//      // throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
//      
//      System.out.println("Inside Step - User gets redirected to opencart 
demo store landing page");
//      
//      // Get the web page title and display it
//      String currentPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
//      System.out.println("The current page title is: "+currentPageTitle);
//                      
//      // Set the expected page title
//      // String expectedPageTitle = "";
//                      
//      // Verify the page title
//      // Assert.assertEquals("Page title didn't match", expectedPageTitle, currentPageTitle); 
//      
//  }

}
But I am getting the following error now in my code -
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null
at StepDefinitions.OpencartDemoNavigation.user_clicks_opencart_demo_storefront_tab(OpencartDemoNavigation.java:106)
at âœ½.user clicks opencart demo storefront tab(file:///E:/Automation%20Testing/eclipse%20_workspace/OpencartDemo/src/test/resources/Features/OpencartDemoNavigation.feature:11)
